# Determinability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables taking values in measurable spaces $(E,\mathcal{E})$ and $(D,\mathcal{D})$ respectively, then we say that $X$ *determines* $Y$ if $Y=f\circ X$ for some measurable function $f:E\to D$.

Let $T$ be a positive random variable and define $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ by setting, for each $\omega$
$$X_t(\omega):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0& \text{if }t<T(\omega),\\
1& \text{if }t\geq T(\omega).
\end{array}\right.$$
I'm trying to show that $X$ and $T$ determine each other.

Since for all $t>0$, $X_t(\omega)=1_{[0,t]}\circ T(\omega)$ and $1_{[0,t]}$ is Borel measurable, we conclude that $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}_+}$ with values $f(x):=1_{[0,\cdot]}(x)$ is measurable and $X=f\circ T$.

On the other hand, one can show that $T(\omega)=\sup\{t:\ X_t(\omega)=0\}$, therefore $T=g\circ X$, where $g:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}_+}\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$ is defined as $g(x):=\sup\{t:\ x(t)=0\}$. How can one show that $g$ is measurable?

Comment: Measurable with respect to which $\sigma$-algebras?

Comment: @ nokiddn : The case $x=sin(t)$ gives $g(x)=\infty\not \in \mathbb{R}^+$, so your function $g$ appears not well defined you should first extend $g$ on $\bar{\mathbb{R}^+}$. Best regards.

Comment: @saz : Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$ and the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}_+}$.

Comment: @TheBridge: thanks, fixed.

Comment: Does taking the supremum just over rational $t$ help?

Comment: @SeanEberhard: I don't see how. Should we take $y\in\mathbb{Q}_+$ we would have $g^{-1}(\{y\})=\{x\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}_+}: x_t=1,\forall t>y\}$ which is not measurable.

Comment: If you define $g(x) = \sup\{t\in\mathbb{Q}: x_t=0\}$ then actually $g^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a little nicer than that: whether $x\in g^{-1}(\{y\})$ depends only on $x_t$ for rational $t$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: right, thanks a lot for that.